# How to properly use smbj to connect and list files on a samba share in Android java?

Tags: java, android, samba, smbj

When I connect with smbj, error log shows:

```
...
I/c.h.s.c.Connection: Successfully authenticated user on 192.168.1.222, session is 4399187361905
I/c.h.s.s.Session: Logging off session 4399187361905 from host 192.168.1.222
I/c.h.s.t.PacketReader: Thread[Packet Reader for 192.168.1.222,5,main] stopped.
I/c.h.s.c.Connection: Closed connection to 192.168.1.222
I/c.h.s.s.Session: Connecting to \\192.168.1.222\pop on session 4399187361905
```

**Immediately** - without any delay.
So the connection is closed immediately after it is opened and it will them crash if I try to list files...

*`Caused by: com.hierynomus.smbj.common.SMBRuntimeException: com.hierynomus.protocol.transport.TransportException: Cannot write SMB2_TREE_CONNECT with message id << 4 >> as transport is disconnected`*

Which seems obvious since there's no open connection.

A question, related to smbj, indicated there was a problem with the way that person used the try statement...  I believe this is a similar case.

Within an AsyncTask, I have:

```
try (Connection connection = client.connect(serverName)) {
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(username, password.toCharArray(), domain);
    Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);
    this.session = session;
    return session;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm certain there's a problem with the try-catch.  Can someone please give a complete piece of code including the AsyncTask - as the smbj module github should have.
I hope this will solve most issues for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a try-with resource block. A try-with-resource block automatically executes `close()` on the variable that has been initialized in it's head (the head is `Connection connection = client.connect(serverName)`). In your case it is calling `connection.close()` when its is reaching the end of the `try` block when it reaches the `return` statement.

If you want to make the connection persistent move the initialization block inside the try-catch block:

```
try {
    Connection connection = client.connect(serverName);
    this.connection = connection; // save the connection reference to be able to close it later manually
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(username, password.toCharArray(), domain);
    Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);
    this.session = session;
    return session;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course you should not forget to manually call `connection.close()` when you want to close the connection. Therefore you should also save the reference to the created connection somewhere, not only the session.